# Save all tkinter GUI to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter

I'm looking for a way to save the frames in a GUI to a pdf (as if they were a picture). So my interface has no canvas, I have a series of frames.
Is there a way to save the whole interface to pdf or image?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a screenshot - there's no built-in functionality for saving the GUI as an image.

Comment: Any suggestion on packages I can use? I mean, I have to add a functionality to save the interface... And it would be good also screenshotting the gui

Comment: [`pillow` (PIL - Python Imaging Library)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but you shouldn't ask for such opinions

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to take screenshots of you gui,
then you can just put it into a pdf

```
import pyautogui

for i in range(100):
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot.save("screen.png")
```

You may need to use

```
pip install pyautogui
```

if you dont have it installed already.